# Rails - Changing the URL for a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following route

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, module: :posts
    member do
      get :flop
      put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
    end
end
```

I would like the URL to be **www.xyz.com/community** instead of **www.xyz.com/posts**. Is it possible to do this without changing the path helpers? I just want to change the URL without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve the issue for you.

```
resources :posts, :path => "community" do
  resources :comments, module: :posts
    member do
      get :flop
      put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
    end
end
```